# Using functional programming, Extract the superclass fields providing subclass object

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8

I have two classes Animal and Dog i.e

```
public class Animal {
    private String name,age;
    //public getters and setters
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    private String color;
    //public getters and setters
}
```

I am using java 8 functional programming to extract the fields from the json node i.e

```
public class EntityExtraction {

    private Function<JsonNode, Animal> extractAnimal = node -> {
         Animal animal = new Animal();
         animal.setName(node.get("name").asText()));
         animal.setAge(node.get("age").asText()));
         return animal;
    };

    private Function<JsonNode, Dog> extractDog = node -> {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName(node.get("name").asText()));
        dog.setAge(node.get("age").asText()));
        dog.setColor(node.get("color").asText()));
        return dog; 
    };

}
```

Th problem is that it's not object oriented. If there is a new field in Animal class then i have to explicitly it in both functional methods i.e 
extractDog and extractAnimal.

Is there a way to set the superclass fields inside the Dog class using extractDog method without doing it via constructor i.e something like

```
private Function<JsonNode, Dog> extractDog = node -> {
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    //extract superclass fields
    //dog.animal = extractAnimal.apply(node);
    dog.setColor(node.get("color").asText()));
    return dog;
};
```

Comment: is there a specific reason why you return a `Function`? Wouldn't it suffice to just use a signature similar to: `Dog extractDog(JsonNode node)` instead? Within a stream you could still call it very conveniently.. e.g. `map(extractDog())` would become: `map(this::extractDog)` (if the method is in the same class). If you then need to call it from somewhere else you do not need to call `apply` but just call it as you would with any regular function, e.g. `Dog dog = extractDog(json)`

Comment: Why write your own JSON serializing library when Jackson has already done it?  I'd only do it myself if I was interested in learning how to do it or didn't want a dependency.  I use Jackson and sleep at night.

Comment: @duffymo i know what u mean. however the jsonNode has these fields named completely differently

Comment: @user2083529 naming isn't a problem, e.g. you can match the `dogAge` JSON field to the `age` field in `Dog`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko the data structure of my model is different than what i am receiving, eg i am getting as json "entityName" instead of "dogName" which i have defined in my model. other than that there are objects which have completely different data structure, therefore i am doing it manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a method* that would give a correct instance for further filling.

```
private <T extends Animal> T extractAnimal(JsonNode node, Supplier<T> animalSupplier) {
    T animal = animalSupplier.get();

    animal.setName(node.get("name").asText());
    animal.setAge(node.get("age").asText());

    return animal;
}
```

After you get an object populated with `Animal`'s properties, you can continue packing it accordingly to the type:

```
Dog dog = extractAnimal(node, Dog::new);
dog.setColor(node.get("color").asText());
...
Cat cat = extractAnimal(node, () -> getPopulatedCat());
```

---

Update:

To avoid refactoring, call the new method i.e `extractAnimal(JsonNode node, Supplier<T> animalSupplier)` from the Functional method `extractAnimal` i.e

```
private Function<JsonNode, Animal> extractAnimal = node -> extractAnimal(node, Animal::new);
```

---

<sup>*To follow the functional paradigm, you shouldn't necessarily be operating exclusively with Java functional types. The above method expresses the idea more eloquently than the private `Function` field does.</sup>

Comment: why Supplier<T>?

Comment: @user2083529 to be able to return T

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the extraction mappings to extract only the fields of the corresponding type and declare them as `BiConsumer`:

```
    public class EntityExtraction {

        private static final BiConsumer<JsonNode, Animal> extractAnimal = (node, animal) -> {
            animal.setName(node.get("name").asText());
            animal.setAge(node.get("age").asText());
        };

        private static final BiConsumer<JsonNode, Dog> extractDog = (node, dog) -> {
            dog.setColor(node.get("color").asText());
        };
    }
```

Each `BiCosnumer` takes a `JsonNode` from which it extracts the values for a certain `Animal` type.

Now we extend `EntityExtraction` by a factory method which will return an extracted `Dog`:

```
    public static Dog extractDog(JsonNode node) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        BiConsumer<JsonNode, Dog> extraction = extractDog.andThen(extractAnimal);
        extraction.accept(node, dog);
        return dog;
    }
```

It takes only a `JsonNode` as input. Since it is supposed to extract a `Dog` it creates an instance of and applies all needed extraction mappings to it.

To map a `JsonNode` we use the factory method.

```
Dog dog = EntityExtraction.extractDog(node);
```

More complex extraction mappings can be build by chaining extraction mapper.

Comment: I liked the your explanation.

Comment: Try the different approaches and you'll see what serves your case best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) and iterate over them. To only get the superclass fields you would need to call [`#getSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--)  first.